# How is state managed in Scala Play! 2.0 Websockets?

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

I'm looking at the example at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat

To make a websocket controller, you write something like:

```
def chat(username: String) = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request  =>
    ChatRoom.join(username)
}
```

Chatroom.join returns a **scala.concurrent.Future[(Iteratee[JsValue,_],Enumerator[JsValue])]** . But where are the iteratee and the enumerator used within the Play! framework? The **WebSocket** class (WebSocket.scala) seems to ignore the inputs:

```
case class WebSocket[A](f: RequestHeader => (Enumerator[A], Iteratee[A, Unit]) => Unit)        (implicit val frameFormatter: WebSocket.FrameFormatter[A]) extends Handler {

  type FRAMES_TYPE = A

  /**
   * Returns itself, for better support in the routes file.
   *
   * @return itself
   */
   def apply() = this
}
```

How does Play! manage the changing state of the iteratee as it consumes input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that the `WebSocket` itself is just a dumb container. The magic happens in various classes within `play.core.server.netty`.

To understand what that magic is, it's instructive to look at the signature of f (the function that a `WebSocket` contains:

```
RequestHeader => (Enumerator[A], Iteratee[A, Unit]) => Unit
```

This is a function that takes a `RequestHeader`, an `Enumerator`, and an `Iteratee`, and does something with them.

So, at some point in the future, the framework will provide our `WebSocket` with a `RequestHeader` (which should be self explanatory), an `Enumerator[A]` (Enumerators are sources, in this case, these are the messages being received from the client), and an `Iteratee[A, Unit]` (Iteratees are sinks, in this case, this is where we send messages to go back to the client).

In the case of `WebSocket.adapter`, the WebSocket will connect the `Enumerator` to the `Iteratee` via an `Enumeratee`. In the case of `WebSocket.using`, the WebSocket will connect the remote `Enumerator` to a local `Iteratee`, and connect the remove `Iteratee` to a local `Enumerator`.

Rather than defining WebSocket directly, it's likely to be easier to use one of the convenience methods in the `WebSocket` object. The following code will echo the previous message received:

```
  def mySocket = WebSocket.adapter {implicit req =>
    var lastMessage = "No previous message"
    Enumeratee.map[String] {msg =>
      val response = lastMessage
      lastMessage = msg
      response
    }
  }
```

Note that this code almost certainly has thread safety issues - in Scala, you should try to avoid mutable state whenever possible, or use actors or similar if not.

Or, try `WebSocket.using`, and look at a pushee `Enumerator`, in conjunction with a foreach `Iteratee`, although it's a little fiddler. Perhaps understandably, the pushee enumerator is deprecated in Play 2.1, as it's being superseded by the new channels system.